# Jsoup return tag with empty body

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying scrap the data from - http://www.giantbomb.com/bioshock-infinite/3030-32317/ . I can get the required tag , but the content inside the tag is missing .

```
 Element element =  document.body().getElementById("site-main").getElementById("mantle_skin")
                                   .getElementById("wrapper").select("div.js-toc-generate").select("form.wikiGroup").first().getElementById("site")
                                   .getElementById("default-content").select("aside.secondary-content.span4 ").first();
 Log.e("hi",element.toString());
```

Code works fine till second last call to "select" . But when i add the last "select" function i get empty tag body .

Output

```
<aside class="secondary-content span4 "> 
</aside>
```

As you can see the element is found but there is no body even though it actually have one when looking at html code . Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: I tried your code now and it gave me result - <aside class="secondary-content span4 "> was not empty

Comment: What did u get between  <aside> </aside> tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine on Java but not in Android . Adding *useragent()* fix the issue

```
Docuemnt doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36").get();
```